# How can I combine two queries with different WHERE / LIKE conditions?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

My two queries:

```
$compareTotals1 = mysqli_query($con,"
    SELECT *,   (SUM(rent_amount)+SUM(late_fees)-SUM(discount_amount)) AS total,
                SUM(late_fees) AS latefees,
                SUM(discount_amount) AS discounts
    FROM        transaction
    WHERE       paid_on LIKE '%2014%'
");
$compareTotals2 = mysqli_query($con,"
    SELECT *,   (SUM(rent_amount)+SUM(late_fees)-SUM(discount_amount)) AS total,
                SUM(late_fees) AS latefees,
                SUM(discount_amount) AS discounts
    FROM        transaction
    WHERE       paid_on LIKE '%2015%'
");
```

How I'm outputting results:

```
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($compareTotals1)) {
    echo CURRENCY.number_format($row['total'],2);
    echo CURRENCY.number_format($row['latefees'],2);
    echo CURRENCY.number_format($row['discounts'],2);
} else { 
    echo "No Records."; 
}

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($compareTotals2)) {
    echo CURRENCY.number_format($row['total'],2);
    echo CURRENCY.number_format($row['latefees'],2);
    echo CURRENCY.number_format($row['discounts'],2);
} else { 
    echo "No Records."; 
}
```

The `paid_on LIKE '% %'` is generated dynamically by a dropdown box and some javascript. That's the only part that changes.

How can I condense this into one query so I only need to use one `mysqli_fetch_array`?

Comment: use a `Union` function

Comment: if you have control over the javascript that generates the query, simply add an OR clause ... `WHERE paid_on LIKE '%2015%' OR paid_on LIKE '%2014%'`

Comment: Do you need both queries? If the dropdown box is to fill in the year then you only need one of these queries, but it would use the year from the dropdown...yes?

Comment: Or are you dynamically creating the first and second year from one single year selected in the dropdown? Or is the year a multi-select?

Comment: @AdamCulp I'm basically selecting two months to compare the results side by side. I shouldve been more clear that there are actually two different dropdowns for the years.

Comment: Sorry for more questions, but: is there a reason why you desire to combine the queries? Not only would it add overhead to the DB, but it would also add time/memory to PHP to parse the results and loop. Are you trying to simplify the return to use via AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want multiple rows a union is likely the cleanest

```
$compareTotals1 = mysqli_query($con,"
    SELECT *,   (SUM(rent_amount)+SUM(late_fees)-SUM(discount_amount)) AS total,
                SUM(late_fees) AS latefees,
                SUM(discount_amount) AS discounts,
                '2014' as Yr
    FROM        transaction
    WHERE       paid_on LIKE '%2014%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *,   (SUM(rent_amount)+SUM(late_fees)-SUM(discount_amount)) AS total,
                SUM(late_fees) AS latefees,
                SUM(discount_amount) AS discounts,
                '2015' as Yr
    FROM        transaction
    WHERE       paid_on LIKE '%2015%'
");
```

You may be able to combine the where's into an `OR` and be sure to spell out a group by or you will not know which is 2015 or 2014 unless * includes such details.

```
$compareTotals1 = mysqli_query($con,"
    SELECT *,   (SUM(rent_amount)+SUM(late_fees)-SUM(discount_amount)) AS total,
                SUM(late_fees) AS latefees,
                SUM(discount_amount) AS discounts,
                case when paid_on like '%2014%' then '2014' 
                     when paid_on like '%2015%' then '2015' end as yr
    FROM        transaction
    WHERE       paid_on LIKE '%2014%'
       OR       paid_on LIKE '%2015%'
   --GROUP BY    all fields from select relevant to group by... without structure and sample data from table can't figure out.
   -- This might work though I'd be concerned all the * columns could be returning improper results.
   GROUP BY case when paid_on  like '%2014%' then '2014' when paid_on like '%2015%' then '2015' end
");
```

maybe... `group by case when paid_on  like '%2014%' then '2014' when paid_on like '%2015%' then '2015' end` but this is very specific.

we might be able to group by paid_on, but it appears it's not just a year... so you may get multiple rows per year... so again without sample data for structure can't figure out what to do.

Or maybe you want a cross join more columns... not more rows...

```
$compareTotals1 = mysqli_query($con,"
    Select * from (
    SELECT *,   (SUM(rent_amount)+SUM(late_fees)-SUM(discount_amount)) AS total,
                SUM(late_fees) AS latefees,
                SUM(discount_amount) AS discounts
    FROM        transaction
    WHERE       paid_on LIKE '%2014%') CROSS JOIN

    (SELECT *,   (SUM(rent_amount)+SUM(late_fees)-SUM(discount_amount)) AS total,
                SUM(late_fees) AS latefees,
                SUM(discount_amount) AS discounts
    FROM        transaction
    WHERE       paid_on LIKE '%2015%') B
");
```

Comment: A `UNION` should get you exactly what you want, but is generally slower.  If you can get what you want with the `OR`, that should perform better.

Comment: In most cases I would likely agree.  However `Or` _can be slower_ than a `union` ***in specific cases***.

Comment: At one point, I was using `OR`, but I didn't use `GROUP BY` this was probably my issue.Is there any way I can associate an alias with the `WHERE` and use it in `$row['total']` ?

Comment: You mean like: `group by case when paid_on  like '%2014%' then '2014' when paid_on like '%2015%' then '2015'`  Now note: this is hard group by.  I personally don't like it.  I would rather find out a way to extract  year. without hardcoding the group by and case statement like this.

Comment: Actually, let me rephrase the question - using your `OR` method, how would I output `$row['total']` for 2015 in one spot, and `$row['total']` for 2014 in another? I guess my biggest issue I'm having is outputting the results one by one.

Comment: I've added a yr  column to the union and or approach so you know which is which.  I also corrected my case statement, it was missing `end`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an OR in your WHERE?

```
$compareTotals1 = mysqli_query($con,"
    SELECT *,   (SUM(rent_amount)+SUM(late_fees)-SUM(discount_amount)) AS total,
                SUM(late_fees) AS latefees,
                SUM(discount_amount) AS discounts
    FROM        transaction
    WHERE       paid_on LIKE '%2014%'
        OR      paid_on LIKE '%2015%'
    GROUP BY    YEAR(paid_on) -- is `paid_on` a date?
");
```

Comment: Because this would result in 1 record not 2 without a group by  (assuming default mySQL extended group by is in place)  and grouping by just paid_on wouldn't work because paid_on could be %2014 blue% %2014 Red% and then we'd get multiple lines per year when it appears only 2 are likely desired.